# How in JS to filter a value on a condition from a map

Tags: javascript

```js
const statuses = [
  "PENDING_SITE",
  "CONSENTED",
  "PENDING_CALL",
  "PENDING_SATTUS"
];

const disqualificationReasons = [
  {
    value: "personal",
    message: "Personal"
  },
  {
    value: "no_nearby_site",
    message: "No nearby site"
  },
  {
    value: "ineligible",
    message: "Ineligible"
  },
  {
    value: "no_contact",
    message: " No contact"
  },
  {
    value: "screen_failure",
    message: "Screen failure"
  },
  { value: "other", message: "Other" }
];

const result = disqualificationReasons.map(({ message, value }) => ({
  message
}));

console.log(result.map((x) => x.message));

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
  <div>${result.map((x) => x.message)}</div>
  <div>${result
    .filter((value) => value === "screen_failure")
    .map((x) => x.message)}</div>
`;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="src/index.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The issue I'm having is that

I have an array of obj the one called `disqualificationReasons` and I'm mapping those in reality to a dropdown menu.

I need to populate the dropdown with the messages but I need to filter when I have statuses as 'CONSENTED' and 'PENDING_SITE'

When I have 'CONSENTED' OR 'PENDING_SITE' statuses I see all the messages in the menu.

When I'm not in 'CONSENTED' or 'PENDING_SITE' the message 'Screen failure' should not be displayed.

I tried to use the filter but got stuck on how to do it.

Pratically based of what the status is on above I have to show all messages or ide the one message 'Screen failure'.

Comment: How do the `statuses` come into play? It's defined but I don't see it used anywhere...Aren't the `messages` dependent on `statuses`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but take a look:

```
const status = "";
const result = disqualificationReasons.filter((e) => {
  if (status === "CONSENTED" || status === "PENDING_SITE") return true;

  return e.value !== "screen_failure";
});
```

In the `status` you will set one of your statuses. If the status is set to `CONSENTED` or  `PENDING_SITE` then the screen_failure message will be shown in the array. If it's not one of those two statuses then the `screen_failure` will be removed from the array.

Comment: This is doing exacly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here:

```
const result = disqualificationReasons.map(({ message, value }) => ({
  message
}));
```

brackets are not necessary. So you could write:

```
const result = disqualificationReasons.map(({ message, value }) => message);
```

Then in your html the filter is wrong because you are filtering using `value` but `disqualificationReasons` has `message`. So the filter should be:

```
<div>${result
    .filter((value) => value !== "Screen failure")
    .map((x) => x)}</div>
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-lake-64824?file=/src/index.js) your codesandbox modified.